# run java file on Terminal (mac) with text file/args

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, batch-file, terminal

I started using eclipse in my macbook pro and wrote program that needs args like (3 1 5)
to work .
The program already compiled using eclipse .
how  can i run it through Terminal with args?
more specific : what i need to do for operate it with file that contain the info.
like batch file in windows?
I am new in the java world so please keep it simple as you can.

Comment: You do it the same way that you do it on Windows or Linux. The "possible duplicate" suggested by @l'L'l has an example.

Answer (score 0):

For an Example.java program with args 3 1 5, enter

```
java Example 3 1 5
```

into Terminal. These arguments will be passed into your Example class's

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method as the string array `{"3", "1", "5"}`.

Alternatively, to accept arguments from a file instead of from Terminal, you might try specifying a configuration file as a program argument:

```
java Example args.txt
```

and then in the Example class, do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filename = args[0];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int firstArg = scanner.nextInt();
    int secondArg = scanner.nextInt();
    int thirdArg = scanner.nextInt();
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: thank you but what i need to write in the  configuration file as a program argument?

Comment: @FuxsA you can write whatever you want in the configuration file, as long as you parse it correctly in your code. In my example above, you would simply write "3 1 5" in the configuration file, which would be assigned to `firstArg`, `secondArg`, and `thirdArg`, respectively.